# Convergence of Infinite Series With Trig functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I need some urgent help in determining whether the following infinite series actually converges or not. Upon graphing, it does seem like so but I can't be sure. I'm not concerned with evaluating this sum at the moment. 
I tried some techniques on http://www.wikihow.com/Determine-Convergence-of-Infinite-Series but can't figure out for some and was indeterminable for others.

[image: The Sum]

[image: The graph]

Essentially if the series converges, that means there's an asymptote and that asymptote is the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use standard Taylor series expansions as $i \to \infty$, to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&(2i+4)\tan\left(\frac{\pi }{2i+4}\right)+(2i+3)\tan\left(\frac{\pi }{2i+3}\right)=2 \pi +\frac{\pi ^3}{6 i^2}+O\left(\frac1{i^3}\right)
\\\\
&\frac{\pi }{1-\frac{(i+2)\left(1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi (i+1)}{2i+4}\right)\right)^2}{2}}=\pi +O\left(\frac1{i^3}\right)
\\\\
&\frac{\pi }{1-(2i+3)\left(\frac{1-\sin\left(\frac{\pi (2i+1)}{2(2i+3)}\right)}{1+\sin\left(\frac{\pi (2i+1)}{2(2i+3)}\right)}\right)^2}=\pi +O\left(\frac1{i^3}\right)
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $i \to \infty$, a general term such that
$$
u_i=\frac{\pi ^3}{6 i^2}+O\left(\frac1{i^3}\right)
$$ and the given series is *convergent* by the comparison test.

Comment: Can you clarify how you found pi+O(1/i^3) for both expression? Sorry for a late question.

Comment: @akirakato You can check the result step by step by plugging first "series of sin((\pi (i+1))/(2i+4)) for i=infinity" into **WolframAlpha**, then  "series of (1-sin((\pi (i+1))/(2i+4)))^2 for i=infinity", and so on.

Comment: By the way, I wanted to know if it converges because I gave up on evaluating that crazy sum. Do you know any potential way of evaluating it?